# Tkinter/Python Canvas doesn't display image from OpenCV

Tags: python, tkinter

I have class `MainWindow` for main window:

```
import custom_windows as cw
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("ORV application")
        master.geometry("500x350")

        # Set container for buttons
        button_container = tk.Frame()
        button_container.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

        # Set get image button
        get_image_button = tk.Button(button_container, text="Get image", command=self.click_get_image)
        get_image_button.pack(padx=20, pady=10, side=tk.LEFT)


    def click_get_image(self):
        # Create window with image
        image_window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        cw.CustomWindow(image_window, "images/tour-de-france.jpg")


root = tk.Tk()
main_window = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

From main class I called new window from class `CustomWindow`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image as pilImage, ImageTk as pilImageTk


class CustomWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master, image_path):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Image")
        master.resizable(False, False)

        # Open and prepare image
        self.image = cv.cvtColor(cv.imread(image_path), cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.render = pilImageTk.PhotoImage(image=pilImage.fromarray(self.image))
        self.height, self.width, self.no_channels = self.image.shape

        # Create canvas to display image
        canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self.render, anchor=tk.NW)
        canvas.pack()
```

Image doesn't display in Canvas. I use `self` to save values from garbage collector.

Comment: You're creating CustomWindow as a top-level window, which means it will display as a separate window, but you're placing the canvas on "master", which is the other window.  I don't think you really want to do ANYTHING with "master" in CustomWindow.  Did you intend that CustomWindow be displayed inside the other window?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I would like to make new window with Canvas, which open when I click on button from parent Window.